# Powershell Changing error output when variable is null

Tags: powershell

I have the following script that I would like to cleanup the error output for. It's part of a GUI app I have made for our team, and is pretty idiot proof, however one user always seems to forget something eg entering the username etc. Please excuse the terrible formatting!

```
if(Get-QADUser -Identity $user -MemberOf $AquaGroup)
{
    [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::MsgBox("$user is already a member of $AquaGroup",'OKOnly,SystemModal,Information', 'Completed!')
}
else
{
    Add-QADGroupMember -Identity $AquaGroup -Member JTC\$user
    if(Get-QADUser -Identity $user -MemberOf $AquaGroup)
{
    [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::MsgBox("$user has been added to $AquaGroup",'OKOnly,SystemModal,Information', 'Completed!')
}
Else
{
    [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::MsgBox("$user has not been added to $AquaGroup",'OKOnly,SystemModal,Information', 'Completed!')
}
}
```

When no username is put in and the tool tries to run this part, it spits out a large number of errors that need to be clicked through.
Would it be ok to add another IF Else section to check if the user exists before proceeding? or is this just going to make it even worse to look at, script wise? Or is there a simple way of truncating the error output to something readable?

Not really up with the play when it comes to error checking.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand the question correctly. You want to check if the user entered a username (which is stored in the variable `$user`) before running the code snippet from your question?

For that you could simply wrap that code snippet in a conditional like this:

```
if ($user) {
  # rest of your code here
} else {
  # display error message or whatever
}
```

---

As a side note, I'd recommend using [`System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.messagebox%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead of the `MsgBox()` method from `Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction`, since the latter isn't part of a default install.

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")
[System.Windows.Forms.Messagebox]::Show('some message', 'title', 'OKCancel', 'Information')
[System.Windows.Forms.Messagebox]::Show('other message', 'title', 'OK', 'Error')
```

Answer (score -1):

using  a `try&catch` can be a way:

```
try
{
  Add-QADGroupMember -Identity existentGroup  -Member nonexistentUser
}
catch
{
  $error[0].Exception.Message
  return #use this line if you want to stop the script execution
}
```

this give:

```
Cannot resolve directory object for the given identity: 'nonexistentUser'.
```